# How to get number of pods runnig for specific deployment in Grafana

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, grafana, monitoring

How can I make Grafana display the number of pods for specific deployment I can see the number of pods in general like the screenshot below shows and is there a way to get each pod how much stayed runnig (the duration between he started and terminated) ?
[image]

Comment: Did you try to list the deployments in the associated namespace?
It can be added easily with a FIlter on the deployment Kind

Comment: Hi your suggestion should work but I prefer to keep the deployment in the default namespace